# Can't get GRASS 7 V.kernel.vector to work on QGIS 2.18.14

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, grass-7.0, qgis-grass-plugin

I have reinstalled GRASS multiple times, with all of the necessary listed programmes to install beforehand (e.g. GDAL), and it won't work.

The error comes up - GRASS was not found in '/Users/Shared/unix/grass-qgis-mtlion/grass-7.0.4' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.

I have tried to redirect it to multiple file locations - e.g. the application in the applications folder, and it still will not work.

Comment: Any chance to update your installation to a newer QGIS/GRASS GIS versions? GRASS GIS 7.0.x is very old...

Comment: I solved this by using a lot of trial and error to locate the correct installation pathway and edit this in GRASS -> Options.

Comment: Great, glad you solved it!